# Oracle function within a transaction

Tags: oracle

I am inserting a record within a transaction and then later I am retrieving the same record via an Oracle function.  The oracle function is returning no records.  My DBA told me that Oracle functions do not operate inside a transaction.  How do I get around this?

Example:
Begin transaction using the oracle provider

Execute some SQL:

INSERT OWNER
(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
VALUES
('JOHN', 'SMITH')

Get the record back within the transaction from a function (71 is an example ID):
select * from table (GET_OWNER_DETAILS_FNC (71) )

Here is the Oracle Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "AROH"."GET_OWNER_DETAILS_FNC" (p_owner_information_oid  in aroh_owner_information.owner_information_oid%type ) 
return OWNER_DETAILS_TABLE_TYPE_FNC

IS 
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; 

v_owner_details_set   OWNER_DETAILS_TABLE_TYPE_FNC := OWNER_DETAILS_TABLE_TYPE_FNC();

CURSOR c_owner_dtls IS
select oi.owner_information_oid, 
oi.first_name, 
oi.last_name, 
oi.company_name, 
oi.license_information, 
oi.company_ind, 
oi.middle_initial, 
oi.title_type_oid, 
oi.suffix, 
oi.status_type_code, 
oi.primary_phone, 
oi.secondary_phone, 
oi.secondary_phone_type_code, 
oi.primary_phone_type_code, 
oi.email_address, 
oi.comments, 
oi.primary_phone_extension, 
oi.secondary_phone_extension, 
poa.owner_address_oid as primaryaddressid, 
poa.address_type_code as primaryaddresscode, 
poa.address1 as primaryaddress1, 
poa.address2 as primaryaddress2, 
poa.city as primarycity, 
poa.state as primarystate, 
poa.postal_code as primaryzip, 
poa.current_ind as primarycurrent, 
soa.owner_address_oid as secondaryaddressid,
soa.address_type_code as secondaryaddresscode, 
soa.address1 as secondaryaddress1, 
soa.address2 as secondaryaddress2, 
soa.city as secondarycity, 
soa.state as secondarystate, 
soa.postal_code as secondaryzip, 
soa.current_ind as secondarycurrent,
(    select
      (    select oa2.owner_information_oid 
            from aroh_owner_aircraft_rlshp oa2 
            where upper(primary_owner) like '%PRIMARY%' 
                            and oa2.aircraft_oid = oa1.aircraft_oid
                            and rownum = 1) as prim_owner_oid
                from aroh_owner_aircraft_rlshp oa1
                where oa1.owner_information_oid = p_owner_information_oid
                   and rownum = 1 
) as primary_owner_oid,
(          select 
              case when (upper(primary_owner) like '%PRIMARY%')
                                                then 'Y'
                                                else 'N' end as isprimary
                from aroh_owner_aircraft_rlshp
                where owner_information_oid = p_owner_information_oid
                and rownum = 1
) as is_primary
from aroh_owner_information oi 
inner join (select * 
                  from aroh_owner_address 
                where upper(current_ind) = 'Y' 
                    and address_type_code = 'OPRIM') poa 
on oi.owner_information_oid = poa.owner_information_oid 
left outer join (select * 
                        from aroh_owner_address 
                        where upper(current_ind) = 'Y' 
                        and address_type_code = 'OSEC') soa 
on oi.owner_information_oid = soa.owner_information_oid 
where   oi.owner_information_oid = p_owner_information_oid; 

begin 

For main_row in c_owner_dtls 
loop 
  v_owner_details_set.EXTEND; 
  v_owner_details_set(v_owner_details_set.LAST) :=  OWNER_DETAILS_TYPE    (main_row.owner_information_oid  , main_row.first_name   , main_row.last_name   , main_row.company_name   
   , main_row.license_information   , main_row.company_ind   , main_row.middle_initial   , main_row.title_type_oid   , main_row.suffix    , main_row.status_type_code   , main_row.primary_phone  
   , main_row.secondary_phone   , main_row.secondary_phone_type_code   , main_row.primary_phone_type_code   , main_row.email_address   , main_row.comments   , main_row.primary_phone_extension   
   , main_row.secondary_phone_extension   , main_row.primaryaddressid   , main_row.primaryaddresscode   , main_row.primaryaddress1   , main_row.primaryaddress2   , main_row.primarycity   
   , main_row.primarystate   , main_row.primaryzip   , main_row.primarycurrent   , main_row.secondaryaddressid    , main_row.secondaryaddresscode   , main_row.secondaryaddress1   
   , main_row.secondaryaddress2   , main_row.secondarycity   , main_row.secondarystate   , main_row.secondaryzip    , main_row.secondarycurrent   , main_row.primary_owner_oid   , main_row.is_primary ); 
end loop; 

return v_owner_details_set;

EXCEPTION
When others 
then dbms_output.put_line ('Oracle error: '||SQLERRM);

end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` pragma means that the function operates in the context of a separate transaction.  By default (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm#sthref1972) this uses the "read committed" isolation level, meaning that, when the transaction queries data, it sees only data that was committed before the query began.  Since the data you inserted has not been committed, this means that the function can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle Docs:

The `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` pragma changes the way a subprogram works within a transaction. A subprogram marked with this pragma can do SQL operations and commit or roll back those operations, without committing or rolling back the data in the main transaction.

Can you try getting rid of that pragma?

Lastly, "My DBA told me that Oracle functions do not operate inside a transaction" is questionable. I'm no expert but I sincerely doubt whether this is correct.